# Some equation with number some without into \flalign

Tags: flalign

I have this:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

%Packs
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{color,soul} %highlight tool
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
    X_c         &= X_{ASV} & \\
    Y_c         &= Y_{ASV} & \\
    \theta_c    &= \theta_{ASV}  & \\
    s_c         &= 2 Z_{UAV} \tan(\frac{FOV_h}{2})  & \\
    la_c        &= \cos(\theta_{UAV}) \Delta_X + \sin(\theta_{UAV}) \Delta_Y & \\
    of_c        &=-\sin(\theta_{UAV}) \Delta_X + \cos(\theta_{UAV}) \Delta_Y & \\
    \gamma_c    &= \theta_{UAV} & \\
    \Delta_X    &= X_{UAV} - X_{ASV} & \\
    \Delta_Y    &= Y_{UAV} - Y_{ASV}
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

That code make a number for all equation, is there a way to remove number in the last two equations?

Thank

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Yes: add `\notag`  in each of the last two equations.

Comment: thank! and how to refer to all of them? \eqref{label} just return 1

Comment: You can't refer to the unumbered equations. For the others, you have to add a label to each, such as `\label{mylovely equation}` and refer it as ‘equation `\eqref{mylovelyequation}`’. Maybe, also think of the `subequations` environment.

Comment: ok, I just want to get: "as show in equation [1-7]" adding a label to the align block, but \eqref using align block label just return "1"

Comment: Using package `cleveref`, you have the `\crefrange` command. In addition `cleveref` will type for you the abbreviated word `eqs`. Furthermore the layout can be customised.